# Treat inline script tags with type="text/plain" as JavaScript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I make PhpStorm treat the script tags with the `type="text/plain"` property as JavaScript? For example the following fragment:

```
<script type="text/plain">
alert("test");
</script>
```

I have tried adding a language injection with the following config, which makes code highlighting work, but code style doesn't work. Every time I reformat the code, it just appends a new line at the bottom of the script tag. It should indent the alert by 4 spaces, just like it does with a script tag that doesn't have the `type="text/plain"` property.

[image: PhpStorm language injection]

The reason I'm using `type="text/plain"` is because I'm using a GDPR JavaScript plugin, that only loads the JavaScript after the user has given consent to marketing for example.

Comment: Hello Vindur, I'm wondering how using this plugin forces you to use `type="text/plain"` ? Javascript `<script>` tags should have no `type` attribute according to W3C validation standard.

Comment: Better use another type if possible. For example `type="text/script"` etc. The `text/plain` seems to be predefined (hardcoded): even though it shows JS syntax colors it still shows up as "Plain Text fragment" if `Alt+Enter` Quick Fix menu is invoked. And yes, that extra line at the end and no indenting...

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass The reason to use type="text/plain" is because it makes browsers not load the javascript. After GDPR consent is given, the plugin changes the type from text/plain to text/javascript, so that the browser executes the javascript.

Comment: @LazyOne That could be a soultion, aslong as all browsers dont output the script to the html or execute the script or any other wierd behaviour when using the `type="text/script"`

Comment: @Vindur then the type attribute should be removed rather than changing it to text/javascript, for it to be valid...

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass On further inspection, that seems to be what happens.

Comment: @Vindur Well, try another one if you have concerns about that one, e.g. `plain/plain` or `text/text` etc.

Comment: @LazyOne that works. You can post that as a answer if you want and ill accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text/plain` type seems to be hardcoded (special handling by the IDE): even though you can make Language Injection to work (the code will be displayed using JavaScript syntax colors) it still shows up as "Plain Text fragment" when <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> Quick Fix menu is invoked inside. Plus that "extra line at the end" and "no indenting" issues...

Therefore try another type, e.g. `text/script` (Language Injection rule works just fine here).

If you have concerns that some browsers may actually execute it (because of the `script` part after the `text/`) then try another custom type, e.g. `text/script-template`, `text/text` etc.